# ¿Conexión a Base de datos Oracle desde c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una conexión a una base de datos oracle, todo funciona perfectamente. Pero el visual me genera un alerta que la clase que estoy utilizando  esta obsoleto. Estoy utilizando System.Data.OracleClient en visual 2017.

```
using (OracleConnection connection =
               new OracleConnection(this.dataSource))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

                        cmd = new OracleCommand("Procediiento”, connection);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Parametros de entrada
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_ID_TRANSACCION", OracleType.Number).Value = latinia.IdTransaccion;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CODIGO_TRANSACCION", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.CodigoProcesamientoTrx;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CODIGO_CLIENTE", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "123456"; //falta definir parametro
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_NUMERO_TARJETA", OracleType.Number).Value = latinia.NumeroTarjeta;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MONTO_ORIGINAL", OracleType.Number).Value = latinia.MontoOriginal;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MONEDA_ORIGINAL", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.CodigoMonedaOriginal;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MONEDA_REFERENCIA", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.CodigoMonedaReferencia;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_FECHA_ADICION", OracleType.Number).Value = latinia.FechaAdicion;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_FECHA_LOCAL", OracleType.Number).Value = latinia.FechaLocal;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_NUMERO_REFERENCIA", OracleType.Number).Value = latinia.NumeroReferencia;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_ESTADO_TRANSACCION", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.EstadoTransaccion;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CODIGO_AUTORIZACION", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.CodigoAutorizacion;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CODIGO_RESPUESTA", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.CodigoRespuesta;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_ID_TERMINAL", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.IdTerminal;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_ID_COMERCIO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.IdComercio;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_NOMBRE_COMERCIO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.NombreComercio;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CIUDAD_COMERCIO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.CiudadComercio;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PAIS_COMERCIO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = latinia.PaisComercio;

                        //Parametros de Salida
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CODIGO_MENSAJE", OracleType.VarChar, 2);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_DESCRIPION_MENSAJE", OracleType.VarChar, 4000);

                        cmd.Parameters["P_CODIGO_MENSAJE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Parameters["P_DESCRIPION_MENSAJE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        latinia.CodigoMensaje = cmd.Parameters["P_CODIGO_MENSAJE"].Value.ToString();
                        latinia.Descripcionmensaje = cmd.Parameters["P_DESCRIPION_MENSAJE"].Value.ToString();

                        connection.Close();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    oracleError = ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Las clases que me marca la alerta son:
**OracleConnection**
**OracleCommand**

¿Porque clases deberia cambiarla?

Answer (score 1):

Valida que estes usando las librerias que agregues por `nuget`

[Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/18.3.0)

si usas la que incluye .net estan obsoletas no deben utilizarse

Tambien esta disponible si instalaste `Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)`

[Installing Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/installODPmd.htm#ODPNT8149)

ya que podras buscas la dll en la carpeta local

Comment: Hola Leandro, con el nuget Oracle.ManagedDataAccess me funciono perfectamente y ya me dejo de dar alertas. Muchas Gracias.